# Iphone SDK:Compiler Bug or Logic Error?

Tags: iphone, tableview

I create a grouped style tableview

and the table has 5 sections ,and each section has different numbers of rows

Here is my code

1.Set how many sections in a table

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 5;
}
```

2.Set each rows in a section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
  case 0:
   return 1;
   break;
  case 1:
   return 2;
   break;
  case 2:
   return 3;
   break;
  case 3:
   return 1;
   break;
  case 4:
   return 2;
   break;
  default:
   return 1;

 }
}
```

3.Give a section header :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 switch (section) {
  case 0:
   return @"Section 1";
   break;
  case 1:
   return @"Section 2";
   break;
  case 2:
   return @"Section 3";
   break;
  case 3:
   return @"Section 4";
   break;
  case 4:
   return @"Section 5";
   break;
  default:
   return nil;

 }
}
```

5.Only give first row in first section data(because others I'm not have idea to set the cell yet)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0) {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; 
  cell.textLabel.text = @"About System";

 }
    return cell;
}
```

**than I got two same Cell in Section 0 Row0,and Section 4 Row 0**

But If I **mark the section header**

It only appear a text label at Section 0 Row 0

IS my switch logic error ? or just compiler issue ????

Comment: What do you mean by "mark the section header"?

Comment: 99.9999999% of the time, when somebody says "Is this a compiler bug", it's not, it's a logic error.  If the person asking the question has less than 5 years programming experience, that goes up to 100%.

Comment: Oh...I only write program about one and half month,mark means use/* */

Comment: like /*- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{...}*/

Comment: my boss is a good MIS & programmer,he said this might be a compiler bug,we use some NSLog(@"create indexPath section/rows")to check how the cell produce

Comment: @Paul Tomblin tough, but fair

Comment: @Paul Tomblin HAHAHAHAHAHA....hope he wont find this page

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a logic error. Notice that you are "probably" reusing a cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Therefore, if you don't set the text label,

- if it is a brand new cell, the text label will be empty.
- if it is a reused cell, the text label will remain the same as previously, which may be `About System` or not.

To conclude, if you don't set the label, there is no defined behavior on what you will get.

Comment: but... it still make no sence when I only remove - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section...than the cell become the result I want it to.

Comment: @WebberLai: Right. The code currently makes no sense besides Section 0 Row 0.